# Python how to convert a encoded payload to a list of byte?

Tags: python

I am actually a beginner of decoding data from sensor.

I got a document of this type

[image]

but I dont how to convert  `0xB84426C3032E28C30328C20228C20226C40326C30226C40326C303` to a slice of byte like the image above.

I tried to search convert int to bytearray. Since when I apply the `0xB844..` above the python code return it is an integer.

Here is what I have tried so far, but not working:

```
bytearray.fromhex("0xB84426C3032E28C30328C20228C20226C40326C30226C40326C303")

75802724735341734603890408823112648684683376170384611767809917699.to_bytes(2, 'big')
```

Comment: For "bytearray.fromhex" to work the first two characters of the payload "0x" must be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to convert it to a binary string:

```py
import re
num = 0xB84426C3032E28C30328C20228C20226C40326C30226C40326C303
binary = f'{num:0>26b}'

print(binary)
```

**Output:**

```
101110000100010000100110110000110000001100101110001010001100001100000011001010001100001000000010001010001100001000000010001001101100010000000011001001101100001100000010001001101100010000000011001001101100001100000011
```

---

Then you can separate these as per your diagram like this:

```py
byte_array = re.findall(r'[01]{8}', binary)
print(byte_array)
```

**Output:**

```
['10111000', '01000100', '00100110', '11000011', '00000011', '00101110', '00101000', '11000011', '00000011', '00101000', '11000010', '00000010', '00101000', '11000010', '00000010', '00100110', '11000100', '00000011', '00100110', '11000011', '00000010', '00100110', '11000100', '00000011', '00100110', '11000011', '00000011']
```